# Tab Position selection Always get wrong position

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabview

Hi I am developing an app using tabs and I am using the same fragment (News fragment.java) to fetch information into list view from different URL upon tab selection but I have a problem when I run my app then it works correctly but upon tab position selection they sometimes show different Tab (URL) info into list view like on the first run my app shows case 1 info into listview instead of case 0 and on direct selection of last tab case 5, it shows case 4 info into listview. What I am missing here

MainActivity.java

```
 ViewPager viewPager = null;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    static String  url;
    private static final String Topics[] = {"Pakistan", "World", "Sports", "Business", "Entertainment", "Health"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        ViewpagerAadapters adapter = new ViewpagerAadapters(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
    private class ViewpagerAadapters extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        int tabCount;

        private ViewpagerAadapters(FragmentManager fm, int tabCount) {
            super(fm);
            this.tabCount= tabCount;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Log.i("Position", "Posotion: " + position);
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    url = "https://www.geo.tv/rss/1/1";
                    return new GeoNews();
                case 1:
                    url = "https://www.geo.tv/rss/1/2";
                    return new GeoNews();
                case 2:
                    url = "https://www.geo.tv/rss/1/4";
                    return new GeoNews();
                case 3:
                    url = "https://www.geo.tv/rss/1/3";
                    return new GeoNews();
                case 4:
                    url = "https://www.geo.tv/rss/1/5";
                    return new GeoNews();
                case 5:
                    url = "https://www.geo.tv/rss/1/6";
                    return new GeoNews();
                default:
                    return null;
            }

        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return Topics.length;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return Topics[position];
        }

    }

}
```

News Fragment Listview.Java

```
 ListView listView;
int positions;
ArrayList<NewsItem> newsItemList;
NewsAdapter adapter;
String  World ;
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.geonews, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_news);
    if (savedInstanceState == null){
    }
    else{
        positions = savedInstanceState.getInt("position",0);
                }
    World = MainActivity.url;
    newsItemList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: could you show me a mainactivity.java in detail? please include onCreate

Comment: have a look at it now

Comment: please give me a xml code in mainactivity. i can't find bug

Comment: The problem is when the app runs it loads "case 1 URL instead of 0" and when I directly select tab instead of swiping the tab then also shows URL of other case.